# Node JS Cannot Use Port Other Than 8080

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, dockerfile, npm-start

I was trying to run npm server on port other than 8080, but it always run back at 8080

example as below, happened similar in many/every method I tried.

```
$ npm start -- --port 3000

> movie-plus-server@1.0.0 start
> node src/index.js --port 3000

app is running in PORT: 8080
```

This occured at the a random event, when I was not using nodemon and making so many changes in my website (so I also rerun the server so many times) without changing the environment

This is on **Windows**.
I once used docker, many options I set them in Dockerfile

```
EXPOSE 5001

# for development
CMD npm run dev -- --port 5001

# for production
# CMD npm run start -- --port 5001
```

and even in docker-compose.yaml

```
  app:
    container_name: cinema-plus-api
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mongodb
      - DB_USER=${MONGODB_USER}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${MONGODB_PASSWORD}
      - DB_NAME=${MONGODB_DATABASE}
      - DB_PORT=${MONGODB_PORT}
```

I also tried:

- many, many different ports
- reinstalling node js
- purging Docker data
- on another project
- creating simple app using npm init and other basic steps
- using the options -- --ports [PORT] and --ports [PORT]
- using .env (which I was sure it won't help, but who knows)
- hoping god would drop a miracle on this

Note that I don't define $PORT anywhere. I didn't even use any variable when I was trying a simple basic project.

This really stressed me out for 2 days as I need 8080 for another application

### edit 1

as asked by Matt, here's a piece of code from src/index.js

```
const start = async () => {
    try {
        await connectDB();

        if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
            require("dotenv").config({ path: path.join(__dirname, "../.env") });
        }

        // very long code

        const port = process.env.APP_PORT;

        // another long code

        app.listen(port, () => console.log(`app is running in PORT: ${port}`));

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        app.get("/health", (req, res) => {
            res.send({ "API Server": "NOT OK" });
        });
    }
};
```

and below is .env content

```
NODE_ENV=staging
APP_PORT=5001
ME_PORT=8082
GMAIL_USER=something@gmail.com
GMAIL_PASSWORD=something
MONGODB_PORT=27017
MONGODB_USER=admin
MONGODB_HOST=mongodb
MONGODB_PASSWORD=password
MONGODB_DATABASE=cinema
```

Comment: Can you include the code you are using to parse the ARGV argument for `port`?  Also where that port value is used in the server setup.

Answer (score 0):

You get the port number from the environment variables:

```js
const port = process.env.APP_PORT;

// ...

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`app is running in PORT: ${port}`));
```

You can't expect your app to magically guess that because there's a `--port` option passed in arguments, that it should use that as a port.

If all you care about is to run the app on port 3000, just update your environment variables. If you want to be able to pass a `--port` option to choose which port then you need to override the value of your `port` variables by reading `process.argv`.

There are libraries to help you do that such as `command-line-args` or `option-parser`